# How to synchronize SIM contacts with android database?

Tags: android, sim-card

In my application I am getting contacts stored in phone, all the updates and queries are also (according to data) stored in `contactscontract.contacts` table in android. Now for getting SIM contacts too I need to import all SIM contacts to the android database before the application starts, or otherwise I will have to rewrite the code again. Is this possible, and how can I do it? I have no idea how contacts are stored in SIM.